# RAILS_CACHE error after updating to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I am doing a rails upgrade from `2.3.18` to `4.1.1` through `3.2.17`

After updating rails and to `3.2.17` and going through each error as it pops up, I am confronted with this:

```
/home/rrw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails.rb:90:in `cache': uninitialized constant RAILS_CACHE (NameError)
    from /home/rrw/Projects/app-rails-upgrade/config/application.rb:142:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/rrw/Projects/app-rails-upgrade/config/application.rb:19:in `<module:AppRailsUpgrade>'
    from /home/rrw/Projects/app-rails-upgrade/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rrw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /home/rrw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I can't figure out why rails would have `RAILS_CACHE` instead of `Rails.cache`. Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Why you'r `application.rb` is so long? And what sits in line 142?

Comment: it contains a lot of configs and some commented stuff and on line 142 it's this: `Rails.cache.logger = Hodel3000Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}_cache.log")`